# How to create the right Enum for an NSAttributedStringKey

Tags: swift, enums

I just startet with swift and now I have a little problem with enum´s and NSAttributedStringKeys.

i want to make:

```
var example: [NSAttributedStringKey: myEnum] = [.foregroundColor: anyColor, .strokeWidth: anyInteger]
```

my problem is that I don't know how to use an enum for that, I tried so much but nothing works or even makes sense.

now im using "Any" instead of "myEnum" but I know that this is absolutely no swift style and it will make problems later on my project.

```
var example: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.foregroundColor: anyColor, .strokeWidth: anyInteger]
```

So how should I solve this?

thanks for any help

Comment: `var example: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]` is correct. What is your issue?

Comment: out teacher says that I should not use it. so we are not allowed to use Any. He said that an option is to use enums.

Comment: You may need to teach your teacher that enums is not a good option here. The values in the dictionary may have variety of type, such as `UIColor`, `NSNumber`... You cannot define an enum which can contain all such types.

Comment: Perhaps you made a mistake about what your teacher was referring to. 
`var example: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]` is definitely the correct approach here.

Comment: so maybe I get that wrong... but anyway thank you guys if you say so I don't touch that anymore :D